# G-twisted Pauli twirl circuit

Tags: information-theory, pauli-gates, noise

Pauli twirls are obtained by taking a unitary $U$, and finding some Pauli gates $P_1, P_2$ such that $P_1 U P_2$. So, for example, one possible twirl of the $S$ gate would be $YSX$.

In the paper [Averaged circuit eigenvalue sampling](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.05803), "G-twisted" Pauli twirls are used. Consider a Clifford $G$ and Pauli $P_a$ such that $G(P_a)=P_{a^\prime}$. Then define the noise gate $\widetilde{G} = GE$ such that $E=G^\dagger \widetilde G$, where $E$ is a noise channel close to the identity. Then, the $G$-twisted twirl of $\widetilde{G}$ is

$$
\widetilde G^{GP}(\rho) = \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{a}P_{a^\prime}^\dagger \widetilde G(P_a \rho P_a^\dagger)P_{a^\prime} = G(E^P(\rho))
$$

Where $E^p$ is the normal Pauli twirl of $E$.

In particular, I'm confused about the last equality. The authors define $E^P(\rho)$ as:

$$
E^P(\rho) = \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_a P_a^\dagger E(P_a \rho P_a^\dagger)P_a
$$

Then, we have that
$$
G(E^P(\rho)) = \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_a G P_a^\dagger E(P_a\rho P_a^\dagger)P_aG^\dagger = \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_a P_{a^\prime}^\dagger E(P_a\rho P_a^\dagger)P_{a^\prime}
$$
Where we let $GP_a^\dagger = P_{a^\prime}^\dagger$. But then, we have $E$ in place of $\widetilde{G}$ in this expression. Where am I misunderstanding this? Additionally, how would one of these "G-twisted" Pauli twirls look as a circuit (or sequence of gates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was misinterpreting $P_{a^\prime}$. This is supposed to be $P_{a^\prime} := G(P_a) = GP_a G^\dagger$. So, the Clifford acts by conjugation instead of only left multiplication. Using this, we also have that $P_{a'}^\dagger = GP_a^\dagger G^\dagger$. Then,

$$
\begin{align}
G(E^P(\rho)) &= \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_a G P_a^\dagger E(P_a\rho P_a^\dagger)P_aG^\dagger \\
&= \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_a P_{a'}^\dagger GE(P_a\rho P_a^\dagger) G^\dagger P_{a'} \\
&= \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_a P_{a'}^\dagger G(E(P_a\rho P_a^\dagger)) P_{a'} \\
&= \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_a P_{a'}^\dagger \widetilde{G}(P_a\rho P_a^\dagger) P_{a'}
\end{align}
$$

Where the first equality came from $GP_a^\dagger=P_{a'}^\dagger G$ and $P_a G^\dagger=G^\dagger P_{a'}$.